# How to skip & character while reading email from gmail in C# using imapclient

Tags: c#, gmail-imap

I am working in a batch process which is written on c# and reads the email from my Gmail account and stores the data into the database. I am using `HigLabo.Net.Mail` and `ImapClient` to read the email. One of my email formats contains "&" character so after "&" character, it is reading like HTML or something else I don't know. Because of that I'm not getting the email properly. Can anyone help me how to fix this?

Sorry I cannot show the whole email the email looks something like this

"Semi Furnished 3BHK Apartment for Sale in Hebbal, Bangalore at L&T Raintree Boulevard...."

while reading it converts to-

> "Semi Furnished 3BHK Apartment for Sale in Hebbal, Bangalore at
>   Lcolor:#010101;width:380px;; line-height:18px.........."

because of some security risk, I cannot show the whole code here..the code looks something like this

```
using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com"))
        {
            client.Port = 993;
            client.Ssl = true;


            client.UserName = "email";
            client.Password = "password";


            Console.WriteLine("Connecting Mail Server.......");
            Console.WriteLine("Please wait while connecting..........");
            try
            {
                var flag = client.Authenticate();
                if (flag == true)
                {
                    var AllFolder = client.GetAllFolders();

                    MailMessage msg;

                    //Select folder
                    ImapFolder folder = client.SelectFolder("INBOX");

                    // ImapFolder folder = client.SelectFolder("Folder Name");

                    //Search Unread
                    SearchResult list = client.ExecuteSearch("UNSEEN UNDELETED");
                    if (list.MailIndexList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //Get all unread mail
                        for (int i = list.MailIndexList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {

                            msg = client.GetMessage(list.MailIndexList[i]);
                            bool b = msg.IsHtml;
                            StoreEmailToDatabse(msg);
                            // break;
                        }
                    }




public static void StoreEmailToDatabse(MailMessage msg)
        {
            sender = msg.From.ToString();

        subject = msg.Subject.ToString();
        edate = msg.Date.Day + "-" + msg.Date.Month + "-" + msg.Date.Year;
        body = msg.BodyText.ToString();

        //int index = body.IndexOf("&");
        //body = .Skip(index);
        string propId = "";
        string name = "";
        string email = "";
        string phone = "";
        string message = "";
        string message1 = "";
        string livservLink = "";
        int p;

        try
        {
            // MagicBricks
            if (sender.Contains("@magicbricks.com"))
            {
                if (subject.Contains("Potential Lead :"))
                {
                    // Prop Id
                    body = msg.BodyText.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\t", "");
                    body.ToCharArray();

                    propId = "";
                    p = body.IndexOf("ID:") + 3;
                    for (int i = p; i <= body.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (body[i] != ',')
                        {

                            {
                                propId = propId + body[i];
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Name

                    name = "";
                    p = body.IndexOf("Name:") + 12;
                    for (int i = p; i <= body.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (body[i] != '<')
                        {
                            name
                            name = name + body[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code where you are reading that mail, a sample of the email that fails and any errors messages you get? As [edit] to your question, please

Comment: The `width:380px` (etc) suggests that the mail is in HTML format - are you really reading it as such? You may need to show more of "StoreEmailToDatabse"

Comment: hee HansKeﬆing there are so many codes inside StoreEmailToDatabse(msg) but i think that's irrelevant, I just used "body = msg.BodyText.ToString(); " and while I am checking the body while debugging it shows this HTML format only, and "isHtml" property is read-only here i cannot change that, can u please tell how to convert that body again to text format or is there any other solution for this

Comment: Hi, @rakeshpanda that's better, There are many ways to avoid your issue, I would like to use the `MimeParser` function available in MailMessage class here (at the bottom) http://library.higlabo.com/Document/Mail/MailMessage.html#Advanced  - this should parse and encode the message into simple text. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: hi @Ali, thanks for the reply. sorry i am not getting any function named MimeParser in mailmessage(my code useing system.hilabo.net.mail.mailmessage) class,also I went through the document which creates a mimeparser object without passing any argument,but while I m creating the same object it is asking for at least a stream object..can u please send me the code how i will use that mimeparser with my "msg"(mailmessage object in my code).